WGAN generating images from the training data



Is it possible for gan to remember somehow training data distribution?
Or maybe somеthing leaks out when I calculate gradients?
for  _ in range(CRITIC_ITER):
        index, (image, label) =  next(enumerate(train_loader))
        sample = torch.randn(BS, ZDIM, 1, 1)
        fake = gen(sample)

        fake_output = critic(fake.detach()).reshape(-1)
        real_output = critic(image).reshape(-1)

        loss_critic = - (torch.mean(real_output) - LAMBDA_GP * gradient_penalty(critic, image, fake) - torch.mean(fake_output))

        critic.zero_grad()
        loss_critic.backward(retain_graph=True)
        optim_critic.step()


fake_output = critic(fake).reshape(-1)
gen_loss = - torch.mean(fake_output)
gen.zero_grad()
gen_loss.backward()
optim_gen.step()


def gradient_penalty(critic, real, fake):
    BATCH_SIZE, C, H, W = real.shape
    alpha = torch.rand(BATCH_SIZE, 1, 1, 1).repeat(1, C, H, W).to(device)

    interpolated_images = alpha*real + (1 - alpha)*fake
    
    mixed_scores = critic(interpolated_images)
    
    gradient = torch.autograd.grad(inputs = interpolated_images, outputs = mixed_scores, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(mixed_scores), create_graph=True,retain_graph=True)[0]
    gradient = gradient.view(gradient.shape[0], -1)
    norm = torch.norm(gradient, dim = 1)
    gradient_penalty = torch.mean((norm - 1) ** 2)
    
    return gradient_penalty


I have found out that for some reason i was using the same batch for every iteration, that is why generator remembered training data
index, (image, label) =  next(enumerate(train_loader))
